# Curve fitting an exponential function using SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have the following "score" function, that meant to give a score between 0 and one for a certain measurement, that looks like:

```
def func(x, a, b):
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-b*(x-a)))
```

I would like to fit it to the following x and y daya:

```
x = np.array([4000, 2500, 2000, 1000,  500])
y = np.array([ 0.1,  0.3,  0.5,  0.7,  0.9])
```

But `curve_fit` does not seems to work:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
```

[image]
When I try to fit it with a linear function `curve_fit` gives a good fitting (in green line), but with the exponential function above it just give `a=1` and `b=1`, that is not a good fitting. A good fitting should be `a=1800` and `b=-0.001667`, that gives the red line (data in blue).

Comment: Could you provide a bit more of your code, including the plot? Then it is easier for others to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is likely that the starting condition is not specified. If you give it as some reasonable numbers, then it is more likely that `curve_fit` will converge. Below is an example with some reasonable starting conditions:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b):
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-b*(x-a)))

x = np.array([4000., 2500., 2000., 1000.,  500.])
y = np.array([ 0.1,  0.3,  0.5,  0.7,  0.9])

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=[2000., 0.005])

plot(x, y, 'x')
xx = linspace(0, 4000, 100)
yy = func(xx, *popt)
plot(xx, yy, lw=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me how can we identify the initial parameter value? in your example how did you select 2000 and 0.005?

Comment: I looked at the data and function that needed to be fitted. For example `a` is subtracted from x, and therefore is should probably be in the same scale. Then `b` probably needs to be in the order 1e-3 because otherwise the `np.exp(-b*(x-a))` would change a lot.